# Cloning a Vue.js object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to log a Vue.js object with `console.log(obj)`, but all properties are displayed with `reactiveGetter()` and `reactiveSetter()` functions instead of their values.

How can I clone a Vue.js object, so that I only get the **values** of it ?

I can't use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` on a Vue.js object because of the circular references (parent, children, etc.)

I tried using `Vue.util.extend({}, obj)`, but this still maintains the data-bindings inside the object.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://codepad.co/snippet/iNH09hM1

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over Vue object properties and ignore all properties with name starts with `_` or `$`.

Like this :

```
var newObject = Object.keys(app).reduce(function(previous, current) {

    if (!current.match('^[_$]')) {
      previous[current] = app[current]
     }
      return previous;
}, {});
```

And result with `console.log(newObject)`:

```
message: "Hello Vue!"
service: boundFn(a)
```

Checks this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Reeska/g5srz7br/